# Puzzled on connect BLE printer from Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, printer

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), where there is BT controller in system.

Now I am testing it with a BLE printer.
I got puzzled when I did following tests.

1. run `bluetoothd -- -d -n -C &`
2. run `bluetooth power on`
3. run `bluetooth scan on`
4. run `bluetooth scan off`
5. run `bluetooth devices`
6. Pair the Linux board with the printer with `bluetooth trust 02:00:7A:05:BF:6C`
7. run `rctest -s 02:00:7A:05:BF:6C`, wait for about 15 seconds, the printer worked.

Then I got a rfcomm_client.c from https://github.com/balle/bluetooth-snippets/blob/master/rfcomm-client.c.

```
/*
  BlueZ example code to build an rfcomm client.
  This code just creates a socket and connects
  to a remote bluetooth device and sends a string.

  Programmed by Bastian Ballmann
  http://www.geektown.de

  Compile with gcc -lbluetooth <executable> <source>
*/

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sock, d;
  struct sockaddr_rc laddr, raddr;
  struct hci_dev_info di;

  if(argc < 4)
    {
      printf("%s <btaddr> <channel> <cmd>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
    }

  if(hci_devinfo(0, &di) < 0) 
    {
      perror("HCI device info failed");
      exit(1);
    }

  printf("Local device %s\n", batostr(&di.bdaddr));

  laddr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
  laddr.rc_bdaddr = di.bdaddr;
  laddr.rc_channel = 0;

  raddr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
  str2ba(argv[1],&raddr.rc_bdaddr);
  raddr.rc_channel = atoi(argv[2]);  

  if( (sock = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM)) < 0)
    {
      perror("socket");
    }

  if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&laddr, sizeof(laddr)) < 0)
    {
      perror("bind");
      exit(1);
    }

  printf("Remote device %s\n", argv[1]);

  if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&raddr, sizeof(raddr)) < 0)
    {
      perror("connect");
      exit(1);
    }
  
  printf("Connected.\nSending data %s\n",argv[3]);
  send(sock,argv[3],strlen(argv[3]),0);
  printf("Disconnect.\n");
  close(sock);
  return 0;
}
```

By referring to the rctest.c, I ran above code in the Linux board, `rfcomm_client 02:00:7A:05:BF:6C 10 "Hello world"`  to send 'Hello World' to the printer, the log said it worked, but nothing was printed.

```
# ./rfcomm_client 02:00:7A:05:BF:6C 10 "Hello world"
Local device CD:9C:8C:87:95:30
Remote device 02:00:7A:05:BF:6C

Connected.
Sending data Hello world
Disconnect.
```

Kernel log is

```
[ 3377.840051] Bluetooth: hu 031a528d retransmitting 1 pkts
[ 3377.846977] rtk_btcoex: hci create connection, start paging
[ 3378.017929] rtk_btcoex: connected, handle 000a, status 0x00
[ 3378.023824] rtk_btcoex: Page success
[ 3378.047249] rtk_btcoex: io capability request
[ 3378.888706] rtk_btcoex: link key notify
[ 3378.932547] rtk_btcoex: l2cap op 2, len 16, out 1
[ 3378.937489] rtk_btcoex: TX l2cap conn req, hndl 0x000a, PSM 0x0003, scid 0x0040
[ 3378.945664] rtk_btcoex: l2cap op 3, len 20, out 0
[ 3378.950647] rtk_btcoex: RX l2cap conn rsp, hndl 0x000a, dcid 0x0051, scid 0x0040, result 0x0000
[ 3378.959714] rtk_btcoex: l2cap connection success, update connection
[ 3378.966218] rtk_btcoex: update_profile_connection: is_add 1, profile_index 3
[ 3378.973533] rtk_btcoex: update_profile_connection: phci_conn->profile_bitmap 0x08
[ 3378.981289] rtk_btcoex: rtk_notify_profileinfo_to_fw: BufferSize 5
[ 3378.987690] rtk_btcoex: rtk_notify_profileinfo_to_fw: NumberOfHandles 1
[ 3378.994553] rtk_btcoex: rtk_notify_profileinfo_to_fw: handle 0x000a
[ 3379.001058] rtk_btcoex: rtk_notify_profileinfo_to_fw: profile_bitmap 0x08
[ 3379.008117] rtk_btcoex: rtk_vendor_cmd_to_fw: opcode 0xfc19
[ 3379.053843] rtk_btcoex: l2cap op 6, len 16, out 1
[ 3379.058794] rtk_btcoex: TX l2cap disconn req, hndl 0x000a, dcid 0x0051, scid 0x0040
[ 3379.066767] rtk_btcoex: handle_l2cap_discon_req: handle 0x000a, dcid 0x0051, scid 0x0040, dir 1
[ 3379.075799] rtk_btcoex: update_profile_connection: is_add 0, profile_index 3
[ 3379.083122] rtk_btcoex: rtk_check_del_timer: handle 0x   a
[ 3379.088817] rtk_btcoex: update_profile_connection: phci_conn->profile_bitmap 0x00
[ 3379.096592] rtk_btcoex: rtk_notify_profileinfo_to_fw: BufferSize 2
[ 3379.103003] rtk_btcoex: rtk_notify_profileinfo_to_fw: NumberOfHandles 0
[ 3379.109845] rtk_btcoex: rtk_vendor_cmd_to_fw: opcode 0xfc19
[ 3379.115646] rtk_btcoex: Delete profile: hndl 0x000a, psm 0x0003, dcid 0x0051, scid 0x0040
[ 3379.714324] rtk_btcoex: disconn cmpl evt: status 0x00, handle 000a, reason 0x13
[ 3379.721942] rtk_btcoex: process disconn complete event.
```

I re-checked the `do_send()` in rctest.c (it uses `channel=10` to connect to the printer in function of do_connect(), I used the same channel 10 when running `rfcomm_client`), and found following codes,

```
577     seq = 0;
578     while ((num_frames == -1) || (num_frames-- > 0)) {
579         put_le32(seq, buf);
580         put_le16(data_size, buf + 4);
581
582         seq++;
583
584         if (send(sk, buf, data_size, 0) <= 0) {
585             syslog(LOG_ERR, "Send failed: %s (%d)",
586                             strerror(errno), errno);
587             exit(1);
588         }
589
590         if (num_frames && delay && count && !(seq % count))
591             usleep(delay);
592     }
```

`num_frames = -1;`, `count = 1`, `delay = 0`, `data_size=127`, it seemd that `rctest` is sending 127 bytes in tight loop, and the printer worked.

But the `rfcomm_client.c` did NOT work.

What is the problem, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

With lots of tests, I think I figured out something.

The printer can work because the `rctest` sends some data to the printer, and the data are coincidently valid printer commands.

So, it needs to turn to the printer's manufacturer for the printer's SDK to make fully control of the printer.

So far, I figured out 2 data frames which can be reponded by printer.  I will ask for the printer's SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The line you sent did not include an end-of-line character (`\n` or maybe `\r\n`, depending on printer configuration).

Most line-by-line printers wait until they've received a complete line before starting to print, and then print the line all at once, to minimize the effect of any mechanical inaccuracy.

Laser printers typically print an entire page at once, and so won't start until they get either enough lines of text to completely fill the page, or a form-feed character `\f`.

Comment: OK, I just tried to add '\n' to the end of the text, and send the data to the printer, it did NOT print the text. I am doing more tests